# How to query an optional column value with a fallback in Slick 3.x

Tags: scala, slick

I want to write a query in Slick that fetches a column if it is not null, or defaults to the value of another column if it is null. How can I do that without repeating calls to db.run?

Comment: Could you show an example of how would that look like? Does it mean that you have some nullable `first_col` and some non-nullable `second_col`, and during queries on `first_col` all null values should be replaced by the ones from `second_col`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean, thanks.

Comment: What version of Slick do you use? Is it Slick 2.x or Slick 3.x?

Comment: It's Slick 3.x, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your table definition looks something like this:

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._ // Import your driver here

class EmployeesTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Option[Int], Int)](tag, "employees") {
  def firstCol = column[Option[Int]]("first_col") // This column is nullable
  def secondCol = column[Int]("second_col") // This column is non-nullable

  def * = (firstCol, secondCol)
}
```

Then your query might look like this:

```
val query = TableQuery[EmployeesTable].map(employee => employee.firstCol.ifNull(employee.secondCol))
val result: Future[Seq[Int]] = db.run(query.result)
```

This way every null value in `first_col` will be replaced by a value from `second_col`. This will be an equivalent of the following SQL query:

```
select coalesce("first_col", "second_col") from "employees"
```

Comment: This didn't actually solve my problem but it does answer the original question eloquently so I've accepted it thanks for the help.